# How to avoid Form Authentication for 2 pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have used Form Authentication in my web project.I don't want Form Authentication for two pages.How can i avoid this ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the following location tags replace Logout.aspx and Login.aspx page names with your two pages name.

```
<location path="Logout.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>

<location path="Login.aspx">
   <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a section to the config to allow anonymous access to certain pages:

```
<configuration>

  <location path="Welcome.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`<location>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx) element to 'granulate' the authentication requirements:

```
<location path="path/to/resource">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>  
  </system.web>
<location>
```

Other than the MSDN documentation, [this is a reasonable post on setting authorization rules](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx), too.

You can also place separate, dedicated web.config files within sub-directories to have self-contained control within that directory - I'm not fond of this though, and much prefer a nicely structured root configuration.